# Network Printing on Win 10 22H2 takes forever

Tags: printing, network-printer

I have an up to date Win 10 22H2, I try to print a document on a network installed printer, each time the print command is sent, it takes at least a minute to be added to print queue, after the job is added to the queue it takes at least 3-5 minutes to print the document. The document itself is just a test page and not big.

Please can you share your experience in resolving this issue. I have already checked the below:

- Windows is latest & no updates pending
- Latest drivers installed for the network printer
- No print server involved
- Cleared the print spooler and restarted multiple times

I suspect a bad windows update caused the delay in network printing, but i cannot seem to find which update is it as the user never reported this error when it happened the first time.

Any clues? Below is the list of updates installed:

[image: Installed Updates]

Comment: If the PC is running normally, then the issue is *communication between PC and printer*, not the Windows OS.  Look to changes in the network and routing, e.g., could this connection be through VPN by accident?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik .. `it takes at least a minute to be added to print queue` implies otherwise from my point of view (I am often wrong and often right).  The network communication or physical hardware shouldn't have anything to do with it until it hits the spooler unless the print driver guy tries to do something outside of the box.  To OP, try changing your Pritner Properties->Ports to FILE: (or even nul:) and see what happens.  Please report your results.

Comment: Also.. the driver IS EVERYTHING.  Including printer model and driver might very well help people in the future.

Comment: Microsoft is actively implementing a plan to discontinue OEM manufacturers printer drivers and instead support universal printer drivers. That plan spans multiple years, even into 2030 and beyond, so it’s unlikely to be directly relevant.  However, my second thought after that potential scenario, is have you removed and added the printer?